# Intermittent conversion warnings when bitwise OR'ing literals in XC8 V1.44

Tags: c, pic, xc8

While composing some bitmask values in a XC8 (v1.44) project I found this rather odd behavior:

```
1:    uint8_t foo;
2:    foo = 0x01;
3:    foo = 0x01 | 0x02;
4:    foo = 0x01 | 0x02 | 0x04;
5:    foo = 0x01 | 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x08;
```

Lines 3 and 5 emit a warning:

> warning: (752) conversion to shorter data type

While line 4 does not. 
I understand the operands are promoted to int prior to performing the OR operation and that is where the narrowing warning comes from. However, why does it only warn on some lines and not on the others?

Is there some kind of obscure C rule in play or is this just a compiler bug ?

Comment: Interesting that this does not happen in free mode where uint8_t has to be typedef'd.

Comment: @cup On my system header `stdint.h` (and thus it's types such as `uint8_t` ) are available in XC8 free mode. As for the conversion warnings, you have to set the warning level to -4 from the default -3 to get them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just another compiler bug, the PIC compilers are quite infamous.

On all those lines, an `int` gets implicitly converted to a `uint8_t` upon assignment (lvalue conversion). A tool that is not broken would report every line or no line at all.

> I understand the operands are promoted to int

No, they aren't, since integer literals are always of `int` type to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it is a bug. You are right, integer literals are of type `int`. The original code uses `uint8_t` constants instead of literals, which do get promoted but I simplified the code in order to post this question, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Unimportant Not a very good idea to ask a question about one code, then post another code. Perhaps there is something in the actual code you compiled that is causing the warning...

Comment: I tested the simplified code prior to posting the question. It behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the literals are native int size (e.g. int16_t for a 16-bit PIC) and the compiler is sometimes warning about the loss of the MSB. I've never seen a PIC compiler complain about a sign change when dealing with literals.

The solution, of course, is to cast the result to a uint8_t. You can also use unsigned literals to keep tools like lint from complaining about sign conflicts.

```
uint8_t foo;
foo = (uint8_t)(0x01U);
foo = (uint8_t)(0x01U | 0x02U);
foo = (uint8_t)(0x01U | 0x02U | 0x04U);
foo = (uint8_t)(0x01U | 0x02U | 0x04U | 0x08U);
```

Comment: I'm working with 8 bit PIC's on XC8. Sadly, casting, in any possible combination, does not remove the warning on this compiler. That seems to be another bug. (?)